# Trying to do math time calculations with SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am writing a SwiftUI app with DatePicker to determine a job's cost based on duration of time.  I can pick the start / end times, but the time interval functions don't seem to determine the correct time duration. I'm only interested in hours and minutes (preferably military time if that is possible) and performing math with these time differences.  My ultimate goal is to compute the cost of the job (in currency) based on time to complete the job.

Also, how do I round time duration up to nearest 15 minutes before calculating job cost?

Here's my code so far:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var startTime = Date()
    @State private var endTime = Date()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Enter Case Times:")) {
                    DatePicker("Start Time", selection: $startTime , displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
                    DatePicker("End Time", selection: $endTime, in: startTime..., displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
                }
                Section(header: Text("Dates Selected:")) {
                    Text("Start Time = \(startTime.formatted(date: .omitted, time: .shortened))")
                    Text("End Time = \(endTime.formatted(date: .omitted, time: .shortened))")
                }
                Section(header: Text("Case Duration:")) {
                    let diffTime = Int(endTime.timeIntervalSince1970 - startTime.timeIntervalSince1970)
                    let caseHours = diffTime / 3600
                    let caseMinutes = (diffTime % 3600) / 60
                    Text("\(diffTime) seconds =  \(caseHours) h:\(caseMinutes) m")
                    
                    let interval = DateInterval(start: startTime, end: endTime)
                    Text("duration = \(interval.duration)")
                    let durationHours = interval.duration / 3600
                    let durationMinutes =
                    (interval.duration.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 3600)) / 60
                    Text("\(durationHours) hrs: \(durationMinutes) m")
                    
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("DDA Rates Calculator")
        }
    }
}
```

I tried using timeIntervalSince1970() and DateInterval() functions but times don't appear to work correctly.  For example, if I select a 3 minute difference in times, it will output 158 seconds when it should be 180 seconds.

Comment: You can use [`distance(to:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date/3329238-distance) to get the time interval between your two dates. Once you have a time interval, divide by 900 to get the number of 15 minute "blocks" in your interval. Round that number up and multiply by 15. There is your duration in seconds

Comment: I do not follow.  Are you suggesting a different function?  How do I use it?  Can you show me in code please?  Also, how exactly do I round that number up to nearest 15 minute interval?  I was hoping SwiftUI had functions that did that for me but I'm finding little documentation on SwiftUI time functions.

Comment: You would start with `let diffTime = startTime.distance(to:endTime)`. Now you have the number of seconds between the two dates and just need to perform the maths. Or you can continue using `DateInterval`, but do not use `timeIntervalSince1970`

Comment: Also, I would strongly suggest you move all of the computation out of the view code. Use a computed variable that you can just reference in your view code.

Comment: As for the 180 vs 158, dates are precise down to fractions of a millisecond, so unless both of your times have the exact same "seconds" you won't get 180. Ie the difference between "10:00:22" and "10:03:00" is 158, not 180 seconds. If you are going to round up to the nearest 15 minutes, then this doesn't matter. If you weren't you would need to use `DateComponents` to just compute based in the hours and minutes and ignore seconds

Comment: As much as I appreciate your help, I'm still not following you.  I guess I really would prefer to see it in code to see exactly what you mean.  I only care to take two different times as input (in hours and minutes) and calculate BOTH the exact time difference in hours and minutes and then to round up to the nearest 15 minutes to make that calculation again.  I don't care for seconds.  I need this in view code because that's the purpose of the app - to show the biller how things were billed in a view.

Comment: Perhaps what I really need is to simply use DateComponents to just focus on hours and minutes.  But how exactly do I extract that information from a DatePicker using a wheelpicker modifier?  Or should I simply have the user enter the time as text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use `timeIntervalSince1970` or the division.  You already have a `TimeInterval` from `DateInterval`.  You can use a `DateComponentsFormatter` to get your string representation.

To get to the nearest 15 minutes you can take the interval, divide by 900 seconds (15 minutes), round up and then multiply by 900 to get back to seconds.

I would use computed variables rather than having all of that procedural code in your view code.

Now, why are you sometimes seeing 4 minutes instead of 5 minutes? I was originally unable to reproduce this as I was using a Playground.  When I moved my code into an iOS app I reproduced that issue.  It is caused by a difference in the way `DatePicker` works in the two environments:

Remember, a `Date` has a seconds value, even if you are only showing hours and minutes. When you initialise `startTime` and `endTime` with `Date()` it is highly unlikely that the seconds value will be 00.  It will be something like `10:20:43` or whatever and both start and end will have the same seconds value because they are initialised at virtually the same instant.

In a Playground, `DatePicker` preserves the seconds, even when they aren't shown, so if I change the end time to "10:25" then the actual `Date` stored in `endTime` will be "10:25:43" - When we compute the difference we get 5 minutes.

In an iOS app the seconds are *not preserved*, so the `Date` in `endTime` is "10:25:00", giving a difference of 257 seconds, which shows as 4 minutes when rounded to the nearest minute.  If you were to change both start and end times and therefore set both times to have 00 as their seconds component then suddenly it starts working as you expect.

The solution is to initialise your dates with 00 seconds.  An extension on `Date` can help us:

```
xtension Date {

    var zeroSeconds: Date {
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let dateComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute], from: self)
        return calendar.date(from: dateComponents) ?? self
    }

}
```

Then we can use that when we initialise `startTime` and `endTime`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var startTime = Date().zeroSeconds
    @State private var endTime = Date().zeroSeconds
    
    private var formatter:DateComponentsFormatter = {
        let df = DateComponentsFormatter()
        df.allowedUnits = [.day, .hour, .minute]
        return df
    }()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Enter Case Times:")) {
                    DatePicker("Start Time", selection: $startTime , displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
                    DatePicker("End Time", selection: $endTime, in: startTime..., displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
                }
                Section(header: Text("Dates Selected:")) {
                    Text("Start Time = \(startTime.formatted(date: .omitted, time: .shortened))")
                    Text("End Time = \(endTime.formatted(date: .omitted, time: .shortened))")
                }
                Section(header: Text("Case Duration:")) {
                    Text("duration = \(self.durationStr) \(self.duration)")
                    Text("duration (15m) = \(self.duration15Str) \(self.duration15)")
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("DDA Rates Calculator")
        }
    }
    
    var duration: TimeInterval {
        guard endTime > startTime else {
            return 0
        }
        return DateInterval(start: startTime, end: endTime).duration
    }
    
    var durationStr: String {
        let duration = self.duration
        guard duration > 1 else {
            return "----"
        }
        return formatter.string(from: duration) ?? "----"
    }
    
    var duration15: TimeInterval {
        return  (self.duration/900.0).rounded(.up)*900
    }
    var duration15Str: String {
        let duration = duration15
        guard duration > 1 else {
            return "----"
        }
        return formatter.string(from: duration) ?? "----"
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Okay - now having the code, that helps a bit.  But it still does not calculate the minutes correctly.  As an example, if I enter a time difference of 5 minutes, it comes back at 4 minutes - off by 1 minute.  I have to show EXACT minutes, as well as hours and minutes rounded up to nearest 15 minutes.

Comment: I'd show you in my example, but I am very new to stackoverflow and I do not know how to post images.

Comment: I also noticed that you converted my times to a string type.  Is that merely to print it to confirm its value is correct?  I was trying to avoid using strings since I now what to take this time duration and calculate a currency based on a mathematical formula.

Comment: I have computed properties that return a string simply because we need strings in the UI; In a "real" app you aren't going to use `@State` variables to store your result. You are going to need to create a view model to manage that.  The code in the view should only be concerned with the view.  I have edited my code to also provide TimeIntervals.  If I set start to "09:40" and end to "09:45" then I get 300.000 and 900.000 seconds for the `duration` and `duration15` variables

Comment: What inputs are using using that gives 4 minutes?

Comment: I wish I knew how to post an image for you to see.  I just ran my app with a start time of 4:20PM and a stop time of 4:25PM and it says the duration was 4 minutes using your "duration" function.  But what you are also saying saying is that I do NOT use @State variables to store my result and instead a MVVM.  Is that correct?  I have just started learning about MVVM's.  Could that be my issue?  I don't really know how to make an MVVM for my app.

Comment: You don't need to adopt MVVM architecture, but you will need to use some sort of model to manage persistent storage of your data.  How you store the data won't change the calculation that is being performed. Does my updated code show that the duration is `240.000000`?

Comment: Please see my second answer above that address your comment about 240 seconds.  Sorry, I'm still learning how this forum website works.

Comment: It isn't really a forum; it is a question and answer site.  You shouldn't add an answer. You should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74366754/edit) your question

Comment: OK, I was testing in a Playground and it was working as above.  When I moved the code into an iOS app, it behaves as you are seeing.  It is due to a difference in the way `DatePicker` works in the two environments; I have edited my answer

Comment: Okay.  That works.  Thanks so much Paul!  Appreciate the help.  I don't know how to mark this as an accepted answer.  I'm also still confused about the the question / answer type format.  Doesn't seem very clear on how to make comments about responses.

Comment: There is an "accept" button near the upvote/downvote controls next to this answer. You make comments just the way you have been. If you want to show an image you can either edit your question or just upload the image somewhere like imgur and add the image url to a comment. You can't add images "inline" in a comment.

Comment: I would really like to move this conversation to chat so as to ask a few other questions regarding my next step with this code if possible.  However, StackOverflow tells me I only have a 3 reputation, not enough to chat.  Is there anyway I can ask a few additional questions about my SwiftUI code?

Comment: Unfortunately until you have sufficient reputation you can only do so through this comment system